# Adjective to describe the relationship of dependence between two courses in university?

Tags: word-choice, word-meaning, word-request

**Intro:** I'm designing a system where I want to show a tree/graph structure where I show which course do you have to approve in order to be able to start another one.
The literal translation from Spanish (my native tongue) would be "correlative" but doing some search doesn't seem to be the case in English.

**Question:** What would be the appropriate word to express that dependence between courses/subjects?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Prerequisite courses** or [**Prerequisite subjects**](http://sc.mdhs.unimelb.edu.au/prerequisites) are the courses that are necessary to be completed so that one may be able to take 'higher' courses. A student should pass all the prerequisite courses before taking the higher ones.

From the link:

> A prerequisite subject is a subject or sequence of subjects which **must be completed before** entering a program of study.

You might want to learn about [**corequisite subjects**](http://www.mq.edu.au/glossary/term/Corequisite):

> A corequisite is a unit of study which **has to be completed prior to or concurrently with** another.

Comment: I never heard this before. +1 for the link. I was thinking of quite a general term - *mandatory*